# Converting a SharePoint List Item to form format and print it

Tags: pdf, sharepoint-online, powerapps, power-automate

I want to retrieve an item from a SharePoint Online list (Office 365) and print it out in a form format. I have looked at a few ways which involve using power automate and third party tools which such as Muhimbi and Encodian to put the item's values into a HTML form template and convert and download the as a PDF. However this solution requires paying for the third party apps which is extremely expensive. Is there anyway that I can work around this. Are there any other methods of generating and printing the form with the values of the SharePoint list item ?

Comment: You may want to try sharepoint.stackexchange.com, which is where the SharePoint community is. Please note that the Muhimbi connector comes with a Free tier that supports your scenario for up to 50 operations per month (note that I work for Muhimbi :-)

Comment: Thanks for your input. Muhimbi is very good but unfortunately I will be having way more then 50 operations per month. Something more in the range of high hundreds or thousands scale. I am trying to look for a solution which will not involve having to pay for any software or services unless there is no other solution.

Answer (score 1):

Oh wow.  I have a ready made answer for this.  Here is how I implemented a print function from within powerapps & flow.  No extra addons or anything.  Just a printer with email and a simple understanding of HTML and powerapps.

Here is the article to get the printer to print:  https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Automatic-Printing-using-Flow-and-a-copier-this-is-a-workaround/m-p/556375

and:  https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Community-Blog/Printing-Documents-Automatically-Using-Power-Automate/bc-p/1636135#M1401

Setting up the HTML is the hardest part.  I did it easily by using Notepad ++ in HTML language mode.  Then plugging in the variables after copy pasting to powerapps collect.  Here is one of the snips of my code:

```html
UpdateContext({PrintStatus:1});'ProcessWorkOrder-2'.Run("<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>TicketNumber."
&Text(dcvTicketID)&"
."& Text(dcvCustomerName)&"
</title>
<style>
div.ltr {
                
                background-color: white;
            }
            #head {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: space-between;

                padding: 5%;
            }
            #head div {
                width: 50%;
            }
            .head {
                display: flex;
                background-color: white;
            }
            .head > div {
                padding: 20px;
            }
            div.border {
                border: 1px solid #333;
                text-align: right;
            }
            
            table.cdata {
                position: relative;
                left: 0.25in;
                top: 0.25in;
            }
            table.cdata1 {
                position: relative;
                margin-left: 5%;
                margin-right: 5%;
                top: 0.25in;
                width: 90%;
            }
            table,
            td, th {
                border: 1px solid #333;
            }
            thead,
            tfoot {
                background-color: #99ebff;
                color: black;
            }
            .bold {
                font-size: 25px;
            }
            img {
                border: 2px;
            }
            p {
                white-space:pre-wrap;
            }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<br><br>

<div class='ltr'>

<div >
    
    
                <div>
                <table class='cdata1'>
                <thead>
                <tr><th class='bold' colspan='2'><strong>Duplicate Print Job</strong></th></tr>
                </thead>
                

                </table>
                </div>
                
    </div>

<br><br>

<div >
    
    
                <div>
                <table class='cdata1'>
                <thead>
                <tr><th class='bold' colspan='2'><strong>Ticket Information:</strong></th></tr>
                </thead>
                <tr><td>Ticket ID:  </td><td> "&Text(dcvTicketID)&"</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Chargeable Call:  </td><td> "&If(tgIsChargeableCall.Value=true,"Yes, This is a chargeable call","No")&"</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Has Been Invoiced:  </td><td> "&If(tgBeenInvoiced.Value=true,"Yes,This has been invoiced","No")&"</td></tr>
                
                <tr><td>Invoice Number:  </td><td> "&Text(dcvInvoiceNumber)&"</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Customer P.O. Number:  </td><td> "&Text(DataCardValue38)&"</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Ticket Status:  </td><td> "&Text(ddStatus.Selected.Value)&"</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Call Type:  </td><td> "&dcvCallType.Selected.Value&"</td></tr>
                
                <tr><td>Date Completed:  </td><td> "&Text(dcvDateClosed)&"</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Closed By:  </td><td> "&Text(dcvClosedBy)&"</td></tr>

                </table>
                </div>
                
    </div>

<br><br>

    <div >
    
    
                <div>
                <table class='cdata1'>
                <thead>
                <tr><th class='bold' colspan='2'><strong>Customer Information:</strong></th></tr>
                </thead>
                
                <tr><td>Customer Name:  </td><td> "&Text(dcvCustomerName)&"</td></tr>
                
                <tr><td>Office Branch:  </td><td> "&Text(dcvBranchName)&"</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Location:  </td><td> "&Text(dcvLocationName)&"</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Make:  </td><td> "&Text(dcvMake)&"</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Model:  </td><td> "&Text(dcvModel)&"</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Serial Number:  </td><td> "&Text(dcvSerialNumber)&"</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Total Counter:  </td><td> "&Text(dcvTotalCounter,"[$-en-US]#,###")&"</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Black Counter:  </td><td> "&Text(dcvBWCounter,"[$-en-US]#,###")&"</td></tr>
                

                </table>
                </div>
                
    </div>

<br><br>

<div class='problem'>
    <table class='cdata1'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class='bold'><strong>Problem Description:</strong></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p>"&dcvProblem.Text&"</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class='solution'>
    <table class='cdata1'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class='bold'><strong>Solution:</strong></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p>"&dcvRichText.HtmlText&"</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<br><br>

<div class='visits'>
<table class='cdata1'>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th class='bold' colspan='4'>Visits:</th>
</tr>

<tr><th>Date</th><th>Time In</th><th>Time Out</th><th>Total</th></tr></thead>

<tbody>"& Concat(ItemGallery_8.AllItems, "<tr><td>"& Date &"</td><td>" & StartTime & "</td><td>" &EndTime&"</td><td>"&Value(Total)&"</td></tr>") &"</tbody><tfoot><tr><td class='bold' colspan='3'><strong>Total Time On-Site:</strong></td><td><strong>"& Sum(ItemGallery_8.AllItems, Total) &"</strong></td></tr></tfoot></table>
</div>
<br><br>

<div class='charges'>
<table class='cdata1'>

<thead>
<tr>
<th class='bold' colspan='5'><strong>Chargeable Items:</strong></th>
</tr>

<tr><th>Item Type</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Description</th><th>Cost Per Item</th><th>Total</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>"& Concat(GalleryChargeableItems.AllItems, "<tr><td>"& ItemType &"</td><td>" & Quantity & "</td><td>" &ItemName&"</td><td>"&Text(Value(CostPerItem),"[$-en-US]$#,###.00")&"</td><td>"&Text(Value(SubTotalCost),"[$-en-US]$#,###.00")&"</td></tr>") &"</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td class='bold' colspan='4'><strong>Total Cost:</strong></td>
        <td><strong>" & Text(Sum(GalleryChargeableItems.AllItems, SubTotalCost ), "[$-en-US]$#,###.00")&"</strong></td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
</div>
<br><br>

<div class='charges'>
<table class='cdata1'>

<thead>
<tr>
<th class='bold' colspan='2'><strong>Toners Delivered:</strong></th>
</tr>

<tr><th>Color</th><th>Quantity</th></tr></thead>
<tbody><tr><td>Black</td><td>" &Text(TK)&"</td></tr><tr><td>Cyan</td><td>"&Text(TC)&"</td></tr><tr><td>Magenta</td><td>"&Text(TM)&"</td></tr><tr><td>Yellow</td><td>"&Text(TY)&"</td></tr></tbody>

</table>
</div>
<br><br>

<div class='solution'>
    <table class='cdata1'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class='bold'><strong>Notes About Toner:</strong></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p>"&dcvTonerNotes.Text&"</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<br><br>

<div class='signature'>
<table class='cdata1'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th class='bold'><strong>Signed By:  "& SignersName.Text &"</strong></th></tr></thead>
<tr>
    <td><img src=" & JSON(Sinature.Image,JSONFormat.IgnoreBinaryData) & " width='450px'></td></tr></table></div></div><br><br><br><br></body></html>","Print_Job_"&Text(dcvTicketID)&"_WO_"&Text(Now(),"[$-en-US]mm.dd.yyyy_hh.mm.ss"))
```

Here is the flow to make the HTML doc and convert it to PDF:
[image]
[image]

Here is the flow to send the email with the attached pdf to the printer:
[image]
[image]

You could morph my solution to do your own thing.  I would suggest automating converting your list to a csv using flow and then converting it to PDF.  Most modern printers support Email, and will allow printing of attached PDFS.  Kyocera is the brand I recommend using.  But I think brother also allows this without having to buy extra stuff.  There is also a python library out there that would let you send info to a printer.